# Haskell: Force floats to have two decimals

Tags: haskell, floating-point, precision

Using the following code snippet:

```
(fromIntegral 100)/10.00
```

Using the Haskell '98 standard prelude, how do I represent the result with two decimals?

Thanks.

Comment: It's supposed to be represented as a string. I.e. 10.00.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just for the record:

```
import Numeric 
formatFloatN floatNum numOfDecimals = showFFloat (Just numOfDecimals) floatNum ""
```

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Done. Better late than never ;-)

Comment: LOL like four months later. :-D

Answer (score 27):

You can use [`printf :: PrintfType r => String -> r`](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/libraries/base/Text-Printf.html#v%3Aprintf) from [`Text.Printf`](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/libraries/base/Text-Printf.html):

```
Prelude> import Text.Printf
Prelude Text.Printf> printf "%.2f\n" (100 :: Float)
100.00
Prelude Text.Printf> printf "%.2f\n" $ fromIntegral 100 / 10.00
10.00
```

`%f` formats the second argument as a floating point number. `%.2f` indicates that only two digits behind the decimal point should be printed. `\n` represents a newline. It is not strictly necessary for this example.

Note that this function returns a value of type `String` or `IO a`, depending on context. Demonstration:

```
Prelude Text.Printf> printf "%.2f" (1337 :: Float) ++ " is a number"
"1337.00 is a number"
```

In this case `printf` returns the string `"1337.00"`, because the result is passed as an argument to `(++)`, which is a function that expects list arguments (note that `String` is the same as `[Char]`). As such, `printf` also behaves as `sprintf` would in other languages. Of course a trick such as appending a second string is not necessary. You can just explicitly specify the type:

```
Prelude Text.Printf> printf "%.2f\n" (1337 :: Float) :: IO a  
1337.00
Prelude Text.Printf> printf "%.2f\n" (1337 :: Float) :: String
"1337.00\n"
```

Comment: I'll rephrase the question :-)
I want to return a string representation of a float with exactly two decimans - not print it to stdout. I can't find anything concrete on a 'sprintf' function in Haskell like I'd hoped.

Any hints?

Comment: Try rounding then printing the float?